Bootstrap grid 3.4.1 mystery
I have a website with a simple bootstrap 3.4.1 grid. All elements are the same. Everything is perfect on all devices / columns widths, except for desktop where I have .col-3 columns and the last 3 of the grid are seemingly randomly placed :
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
X
XX
If I set it back to .col-4 for the same device, the grid works perfectly.
I checked every possible thing, no special css for any of the elements, everything is the same size etc. and was wondering, if there anything you could think of that could be causing this?
Thank you,

Please add enough relevant code (as text) inside the question in order to create a [mre] - [ask]

There's just too much going on to do that I'm afraid. This is the page:
http://mamahuhu.studio/work.html
But the grid itself is a very basic grid, and was wondering if there's a usual approach if something like this happens.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?
